# ASP.NET MVC replicate Active Directory user details into database table

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I have an intranet application that uses Active Directory to handle access and roles. This all works well.

Within my application there is a `Customer` database. Each `Customer` can have multiple categories with a member of staff assigned to each of them. With this in mind to help cut down on the number of queries to Active Directory I thought it would be easier to have a copy of my Active Directory users and some of their details in my database so I can create navigation properties between my models.

Can anyone suggest a method to replicate some of the fields from Active Directory into my SQL Server database? I only need `Firstname`, `Surname`, `EmployeeID`, `Email`, etc.

It would be useful if this ran hourly/daily.

Comment: Here are two articles that might be of some help: [Querying AD from SQL Server](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2580/querying-active-directory-data-from-sql-server/) and [Syncronizing AD Objects to SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720650(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885337/active-directory-data-into-sql-table and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782292/synchronization-between-c-sharp-app-and-active-directory

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a database product... it would really help to know what **database system** you're using....

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server. @marcs could you elaborate on http://stackoverflow.com/a/4885501/1472203 as I currently use PrincipalContext to get details on the current user.